# Проблема с переменной, видимой всем потокам

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте!

Не получается сделать для потоков общую переменную.
Нужно при закрытии приложения завершать все потоки... Что я делал:

```
public class Worker{

    // Закрыть потоки при клике на ...
    private static boolean breackOnCloseUnloader=false, breackOnCloseLoader=false;

    // Потоки
    Thread loader, unloader, waiter;

    // Стартуем потоки!!!
    public Worker() {
        // запускаем потоки погрузки и разгрузки
        loader = new Loader();
        loader.start();
        unloader = new Unloader();
        unloader.start();

        new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    loader.join(); // ждем
                }
                catch(InterruptedException e){}
            }           
        }.start();
    }

    public class Unloader extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            try{
                while (!isInterrupted()) {  
                    if(breackOnCloseUnloader)
                        break;// Завершение потока

                    ...
                }
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
            }
            breackOnCloseLoader=true;
        }

    }
    public class Loader extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            try {
                while(true) {
                    if(breackOnCloseLoader)
                        break;// Завершение потока
                    ...
                } 
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Чего хочу добится: есть окно, при нажатии на крестик нужно breackOnCloseUnloader выставлять в 1 и он вырубит один из потоков, который в свою очередь должен выставить флаг breackOnCloseLoader, который вырубит другой поток...
В потоке фрейма я создаю др. поток, который ожидает завершения потоков Loader и Unloader... Пока всё работет непонятно как... Почему переменная с идентификатором статик в классе Worker не является уникальной для всех потоков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Alerr, я тут мимокрокодил, но интернет говорит, что переменную нужно объявлять как volatile (например, вопрос на хэшкоде)